# BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc - even that it does

Tags: flutter, navigation, bloc, flutter-bloc

First of, I do know how BLoC suppose to work, the idea behind it and I know the difference between `BlocProvider()` and `BlocProvider.value()` constructors.

For simplicity, my application has 3 pages with a widget tree like this:

`App()` => `LoginPage()` => `HomePage()` => `UserTokensPage()`

I want my `LoginPage()` to have access to `UserBloc` because i need to log in user etc. To do that, I wrap `LoginPage()` builder at `App()` widget like this:

```
void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      home: BlocProvider<UserBloc>(
        create: (context) => UserBloc(UserRepository()),
        child: LoginPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That obviously works just fine. Then, if *User* logs in successfully, he is navigated to `HomePage`. Now, I need to have access to two different blocs at my `HomePage` so I use `MultiBlocProvider` to pass existing `UserBloc` further and create a brand new one named `DataBloc`. I do it like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<UserBloc, UserState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is UserAuthenticated) {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute<HomePage>(
              builder: (_) => MultiBlocProvider(
                providers: [
                  BlocProvider.value(
                    value: BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context),
                  ),
                  BlocProvider<DataBloc>(
                    create: (_) => DataBloc(DataRepository()),
                  ),
                ],
                child: HomePage(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
[...]
```

This also works. Problem happens when from `HomePage` *user* navigates to `UserTokensPage`. At `UserTokensPage` I need my already existing `UserBloc` that I want to pass with `BlocProvider.value()` constructor. I do it like this:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        title: Text('My App'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          CustomPopupButton(),
        ],
      ),

[...]

class CustomPopupButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomPopupButton({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopupMenuButton<String>(
      icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
      onSelected: (String choice) {
        switch (choice) {
          case PopupState.myTokens:
            {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute<UserTokensPage>(
                  builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
                    value: BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context),
                    child: UserTokensPage(),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
            break;
          case PopupState.signOut:
            {
              BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context).add(SignOut());
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }
        }
      },
[...]
```

When I press button to navigate to `MyTokensPage` i get error with message:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Builder(dirty):
        BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type UserBloc.

        No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>().

        This can happen if:
        1. The context you used comes from a widget above the BlocProvider.
        2. You used MultiBlocProvider and didn't explicity provide the BlocProvider types.

        Good: BlocProvider<UserBloc>(create: (context) => UserBloc())
        Bad: BlocProvider(create: (context) => UserBloc()).

        The context used was: CustomPopupButton
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it because i have extracted `PopupMenuButton` widget that somehow loses blocs? I don't understand what I can be doing wrong.

Comment: Why you need a BlocListener to navigate to the next page? I think this can be accomplished in a simpler way using `BlocBuilder` and return the page you need to return when `UserAuthenticated`

Comment: @StefanoSaitta I did it this way because thats what official flutter_bloc [documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=bloclistener) for BlocListeners recomends to do.

Comment: @Stahp give my answer a try and let me know of the result.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**EDIT 10/03/2022**

Since this thread became very popular I feel I need to add some comments.

This is valid solution if your goal is to use blocs that are **not** provided above your `MaterialApp` widget, but instead being declared somewhere down the widget tree by wrapping your widget (eg. some page) with `BlocProvider` making it possible for that widget to access the bloc.

It is easier to avoid problems by declaring all your blocs in `MultiBlocProvider` somewhere up the widget tree (like I said before), but this topic was not created with that in mind. Feel free to upvote and use this aproach described in *Amesh Fernando* response but do that knowing the difference.

---

I fixed it. Inside `App` widget i create `LoginPage` with

```dart
home: BlocProvider<UserBloc>(
        create: (context) => UserBloc(UserRepository()),
        child: LoginPage(),
```

At `LoginPage` I simply wrap `BlocBuilders` one into another

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<UserBloc, UserState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is UserAuthenticated) {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute<HomePage>(
              builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
                value: BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context),
                child: BlocProvider<NewRelicBloc>(
                  create: (_) => NewRelicBloc(NewRelicRepository()),
                  child: HomePage(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
[...]
```

`PopupMenuButton` navigates *User* to `TokenPage` with

```dart
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute<UserTokensPage>(
                  builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
                    value: BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context),
                    child: UserTokensPage(),
                  ),
                ),
              );
```

And that solved all my problems.

Comment: It's worth noting that using the name `context` for every context object can really confuse things (that's why we name our variables clearly and cleanly). I've found naming each context separately helps track down where there confusion may be with providers. Your underscore approach worked but may still cause confusion if you end up with nested underscore contexts.

Answer (score 37):

You can just wrap the Blocs you need to access through out the app by wrapping it at the entry point of the app like this

```
  runApp(
      MultiBlocProvider(
          providers: [
            BlocProvider<UserBloc>(
              create: (context) =>
                  UserBloc(UserRepository()),
            ),

          ],
          child: App()
      )
  );
}
```

and you can access this bloc at anywhere of your app by

`BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context).add(event of user bloc());`

Comment: Do I have to implement each Bloc in this way in main.dart file? Can you explain why should we do this? Your answer has saved me. Thank you

Comment: No, but you can't provide it on the current page(the page you are currently at). Either you can provide it before navigating to a specific page or on the main.dart file.

Comment: Its simple and real solution. Thanks!

Comment: Damn simple solution. Its a hell working with those context.

Comment: @AmeshFernando you actually can provide it on current page by using builder between blocProvider and BlocListener

Comment: @AmeshFernando. thanks. moving the bloc provider(s) up from material app did the trick

Answer (score 11):

**Change name of context in builder whether in bottomSheet or materialPageRoute.**

So that bloc can access parent context through context
unless it's going to take context from builder (bottom sheet). This can lead
to an error which you can't reach the instance of bloc .

```
showModalBottomSheet(
     context: context,
     builder: (context2) {  ===> change here to context2
     BlocProvider.value(
          value: BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context),
          child: widgetA(),
                       ),
     }
```

Comment: This is so helpful. Thank you!

Comment: this actually the rootcasue of my problem, thanks

Comment: This answer is underrated. It was the solution I was looking for. Kudos.

Answer (score 7):

## Solution

### Method A: Access `UserBloc` provider instance directly without passing it

I prefer this solution since it requires less code.

#### A.1 Wrap `CustomPopupButton` instance with provider [Consumer](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html) so it rebuilds itself whenever UserBloc notifies listeners of value changes.

Change this:

```dart
actions: <Widget>[
    CustomPopupButton(),
],
```

To:

```dart
actions: <Widget>[
    Consumer<UserBloc>(builder: (BuildContext context, UserBloc userBloc, Widget child) {
      return CustomPopupButton(),
    });
],
```

#### A.2 Change Provider instance invocation inside the stateless widget to disable listening to value changes -- "listening" and resulting "rebuilds" are already done by `Consumer`.

**A.2.1** Change this:

```dart
value: BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context),
```

To:

```dart
value: BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context, listen: false),
```

**A.2.2** And change this:

```dart
BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context).add(SignOut());
```

To:

```dart
BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context, listen: false).add(SignOut());
```

### Method B: pass `UserBloc` provider instance

Same thing as Method A, but:

- In A.1 you'd pass `userBloc` like this: `return CustomPopupButton(userBloc: userBloc),`.
- You'd declare `final UserBloc userBloc;` member property inside `CustomPopupButton`.
- In A.2 you'd do this: `userBloc.add(SignOut());` instead of `BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context, listen: false).add(SignOut());`

## Explanation

`flutter_bloc` is using [`Provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), to be aware what's going on it's better understand Provider. Please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59900307/10830091) to understand my answer to your question, and to understand Provider and `listen` flag better.

Comment: Give this solution a try and let me know if it worked. Can't test it. It'd be great if you'd provided your `Provider` types implementations.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution. Unfortunately, flutter_bloc Provider.of<T>(context) does not have `listen` parameter which i can set to false as said at A.2.1. Furthermore, after wrapping CustomPopupButton with ConsumerBloc (without changing Provider.of() ) CustomPopup widget crashes and does not render because "BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type UserBloc.". It seems UserBloc creation fails already at LoginPage but due MultiBlocProvider it doesnt crash app.

Comment: @Stahp Well you're in luck. `flutter_bloc` is already [doing that](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/b63c675e7b724a7defbf99b25b652cfecd98f7b3/packages/flutter_bloc/lib/src/bloc_provider.dart#L104). So you don't need to specify `listen: false` as it's already done for you. I'll update my answer when I get to with some possible fixes and notify you when done.

Comment: would you mind to help me on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73149700/i-want-to-call-an-event-with-my-bloc-using-flutter-in-a-class-where-my-bloc-has

Comment: @MarcelDz I see it was already answered, glad it did.

Answer (score 3):

You need to either decompose your widget into two widgets (which I recommend for testability reasons) or use a Builder widget to get a child context.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget { 
  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return BlocProvider( create: (_) => TestCubit(), child: MyHomeView(), ); 
  }
}

class MyHomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return Scaffold( body: Center( child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () => BlocProvider.of<TestCubit>(context)...) ), ); 
    } 
  }
```

source: solved by Felix Angelov, https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/2064

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use BlocProvider.value() to navigate to another screen, you can just wrap MaterialApp into BlocProvider as a child of it